# Why would persisting RDD to DISK NOT improve performance?

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following DAG

1. Generate an RDD with 200 million records
2. Persist the RDD to disk (StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY())
3. Filter every even record in the RDD (50% of the records)
4. Store to Disk (`saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`)
5. Filter every odd record in the RDD (50% of the records)
6. Store to Disk (`saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`)

The size of the RDD on disk is **100GB**

The total number of time taken to accomplish the first action (step 4) is **10 minutes**

I would have thought that for the second action (step 6) the RDD would be loaded from disk filtered, etc.  Taking much shorter time.

But in fact it takes the same amount of time **10 minutes**!

Would loading the 100GB rdd from disk really cost the same amount of time as generating the rdd?

What could explain this?  Am I hitting some sort of IO bottleneck?  How can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job chaining : where you want to run multiple jobs with one job depending on output of previous .

MapReduce pardigm :  1MR job => saves output on HDFS => Read from HDFS 2 MR job => .......

Spark =>  try to hold as much data as possible in memory , else we are getting into the inefficiencies of MapReduce paradigm .

Now coming to your question :

> 1. Spark will do some optimization while saving data on disk , but its no compared to in Memory.
> 2. Spark generates a chain of MapTask and Reduce Task. We should try to hold as much data in memory as possible , best case try to complete
>      the task in only one MR task.

For a indepth understaning please follow

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/